# Resolving resx references

Tags: .net, asp.net, visual-studio, resx

When I compile my .NET 1.1 ASP.NET app, I'm getting RESX reference problems.  How can I easily force VS2003 to dump all these references (I'm not using them) and force a rebuild of them?

Comment: Unfortunately (for you), the number of people still running VS2003 is quite low - I wish you the best of luck, but...

Comment: There actually probably more people running VS 6.0 than VS 2003 :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a text editor that allows you to use regular expressions and do a find and replace on this regex

^.*\n.*resx\"\n.*\n.*EmbeddedResource.*\n.*

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Danny, I would open the .sln file to see where is it referencing the conflicting RESX and get rid of them.